# How to compile Java EE Source (ejb) code

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have installed JDK 7 and java EE sdk 6 with glassfish server, I am not using any IDE, just text editor, Which jar files of EE implementation should i add to classpath in order to compile the ejb code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is the list of jars provided by GF 3.1.2]

You can see on the uploaded picture a list of jars provided by Glassfish 3.1.2. Depending on the type of project (Web application, pure EJB etc.) you need only some of them (e.g. if you won't deal with Java Mail API, you don't need javax.mail.jar), but to avoid problems later I would suggest including majority of them in your classpath.